# Gradle build daemon disappeared

Tags: android, cordova, gradle

I new in development hybrid mobile and I was trying all my day configure and install Cordova and Android SDK, and it was the most difficult thing I have done.

I just can't make build a Android app, every time give me a error, when I fix, give me another, and don't have finished. Now I came in a error that I can't resolve, I tried all questions here and nothing works

Basically I have this error now:

> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong:
>   Gradle build daemon disappeared unexpectedly (it may have been killed or may have crashed)

I almost given up or try to find a Vagrant environment.